# Using a class object implicitly as a condition c++

Tags: c++, class, if-statement

I have some class called `GY`.

```
class GY
{
public: 
...
private: 
...
int data = -1;    
}
```

Let's say that if an object `gy` of the class `GY` has `data` with positive integer an `if(gy)` operation will return `bool`. Otherwise `false`.
What is the way to make the operation work implicitly?

Comment: Are asking about a user defined conversion to `bool`?

Comment: @StoryTeller yes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The C++11 way of doing it is overloading `explicit operator bool()` (see [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators)), if you are using an older standard see [here.](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Safe_bool)

Comment: if I use only `operator bool()` without `explicit` what is difference?

Comment: @axcelenator Then you get confused as to why `int x = gy + 3` compiles, because of the sequence of "implicit conversion to `bool` then integer promotion"